# General guidelines for choosing 訓読み vs. 音読み in kanji reading

Tags: kanji, readings, compounds

I am trying to come up with general rules for *kanji* reading. So far I have the following down:

> 1. Compound *kanji* words are read as *on'yomi*
> 2. Single *kanji* words are read as *kun'yomi*
> 3. Verbs composed *kanji* followed by *okurigana* are read as *kun'yomi*
> 4. Geographical and personal names are read as *nanori*
> 5. Exceptions to the above that need to be memorized

Are there any other guidelines?

Comment: Nearly all of these "rules" are plagued withe exceptions. For rule #1, 割込、受付、出来る; for rule #2 勘、信; for rule #3, 信じる , 応じる, ...

Comment: I fully agree with Virmaior-san's comment. It should be posted as the answer.

Comment: @virmaior Your exceptions are covered by rule 5. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you correctly identified very broad tendencies. However, as noted in the comments, there are many counterexamples to each one of your first four rules, so many that they shouldn't fall under rule 5 "exceptions".

> 1. Compound *kanji* words are read as *on'yomi*

There are many pure *kun'yomi* compounds

> 場合、子供、言葉、相手、部屋、手紙、…

and compounds with mixed readings (called *jūbako yomi* or *yutō yomi*, see [Can a Japanese word combine both on'yomi and kun'yomi characters?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40433/1628)).

---

> 2. Single *kanji* words are read as *kun'yomi*

Again, not always.

> 気、本、図、点、例、文、席、…

---

> 3. Verbs composed *kanji* followed by *okurigana* are read as *kun'yomi*

There is a broad class of verbs derived from so-called "*suru* verbs", which take an *on'yomi* *kanji* and some form of *suru* that has changed through sound change

> 愛す、通じる、投じる、信じる、講ずる、案ずる、…

However, this class is easily identified, so you may also put it under the "exceptions" rule.

---

> 4. Geographical and personal names are read as *nanori*

Not every name is a *nanori* reading (unless you say that *nanori* readings *include* all standard readings, in which case this isn't really a rule at all).

> 小林 愛子、林 愛、黒川 慎太郎

(Then, the only rule I can think of for reading names is "anything goes". Also see [Both on'yomi and kun'yomi in a first name?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41404/1628))

---

Rule 5, however, is a good rule.

> 5. Exceptions to the above that need to be memorized

There will **always** be exceptions that need to be memorized.