# Is it correct to read 黒川 as くろかわ or is くろがわ correct?

Tags: pronunciation, names

I always run into this problem.

Sometimes か and が are very similar to me so I have to type them in the computer to find the correct pronunciation of word.

When I type くろがわ or くろかわ they both give me 黒川. So which one is correct? Or are they both correct?

(I am using the Microsoft IME input) If only one is correct, why does this input method suggest the kanji that I wanted? Isn't that misleading?

Comment: Related:  [Which readings would you use to pronounce people's names?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5529/78).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are "correct" readings.

Since 「黒川」 is a ***proper noun***, no one correct reading exists in the first place.  Because it is a proper noun, however, only one reading is correct for each instance where a name, place, river, etc. is named 「黒川」.

It is ***not*** the same thing as reading a regular noun/word in two different ways where one could choose one over the other.

For instance, near where I live in Nagoya, there is an area (and a subway station) named 「黒川」 and it is officially read 「くろ**か**わ」.  Reading it 「くろ**が**わ」 would be out of the question for us local residents.

[黒川駅 (愛知県)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BB%92%E5%B7%9D%E9%A7%85_(%E6%84%9B%E7%9F%A5%E7%9C%8C))

An area in Saga Prefecture, however, is named 「黒川」 as well, but it is read 「くろ**が**わ」.  If I read it 「くろかわ」, I would probably look like a foreigner to the locals there.

[黒川(佐賀県)くろがわ](https://www.navitime.co.jp/bus/aroundBusStop/?node=00291851)

Comment: ^うわ～。。。仕返しかいな・・

Answer (score 1):

くろかわ Is the most likely the most used , I have not heard くろがわ used around  where I live, but it may be used somewhere.

So to answer your question, it is くろかわ that is the most used reading of 黒川.