# How to read the names 勲 and 房子

Tags: kanji, names

Do any of you know which names these 2 kanji are in rōmaji?

[image]

Comment: Related:  [Which readings would you use to pronounce people's names?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5529/78)

Answer (score 2):

Names are always a tricky business, as for names the reading need not bear any relation to the *kanji* at all. Of course, usually there is some connection, but the best one can do is to venture an educated guess.

The names you posted are quite possibly

- 勲 いさお *Isao*
- 房子 ふさこ *Fusako*

but you should try to confirm this, asking the person (or someone who knows them).