# Why is 江風 being translated to Kawakaze even though there's no Kawa in the kanji?

Tags: kanji, readings, names

I am studying Japanese and I am also a bit of an *Azur Lane* fan (a gacha game). One of my favorite characters is called Kawakaze, based on the real-life IJN [Kawakaze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_destroyer_Kawakaze_(1936)) (a Shiratsuyu-class destroyer). The kanji that are being used are 江風 which translates to "Bay Wind", even though "River Wind" seems to be much more popular for some reason.

I looked these kanji up and I notice a problem. The first one ("Bay", "Creek", "Inlet") has no reading that translates to "Kawa". The second is "Kaze" meaning "wind".

How's that possible? I did some looking around and her *Kancolle* (a similar gacha game) counterpart actually has a note on her [page](https://en.kancollewiki.net/w/index.php?title=Kawakaze) that says

> Her kanji "江風" would more commonly be read as "Ekaze" instead of "Kawakaze".

There's even a [voiceline](https://kancolle.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:Mystia_Lore./Counterattack_!_The_Second_Operation_SN) that goes like this.

> Kawakaze : YO ! The 9th Shiratsuyu-class Destroyer, Kawakaze of the revised Shiratsuyu-class. Nice to meet you ! Ah, about the reading of my name, do not get it wrong ! It's KAWAKAZE, not Ekaze !
>
> Myschin : Ekaze and Kawakaze doesn't sound alike at all ! I won't make that kind of mistake but...

So how does this happen? Is this something unique to warships or is there some funkiness going on that I just don't understand. I am a beginner, so this might just be a very simple thing that I just don't understand. [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B1%9F%E9%A2%A8) says 江 only has two readings: え and コウ, but not かわ.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. This is a site for questions about methods for learning  or teaching language. Questions asking to explain some aspect of the grammar or vocabulary of a specific language are off topic here. I hope your question will be better received on Japanese Language Stack Exchange.

Comment: Related:  [Which readings would you use to pronounce people's names?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5529/78https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5529/78)

Comment: I think that link should be https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/which-readings-would-you-use-to-pronounce-peoples-names

Answer (score 4):

The kanji 江 does mean "river", too, although this meaning is almost obsolete. See [this entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B1%9F-1). For example, 江 is in the name of 長江 ([Yangtze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangtze)). [This page](https://chu-channel.com/%E5%B7%9D%E3%81%A8%E6%B2%B3%E3%81%A8%E6%B1%9F-7110) (written in Japanese) explains the differences of three kanji that means "river" (川, 河, 江).

As for the reading, the only "official" kun-reading of 江 is え today, but the readings of kanji were not very standardized in the past. Since 江 meant "river", かわ could have been recognized as a valid kun-reading of 江 in the past. In addition, kanji in proper nouns can have lots of unpredictable readings (sometimes referred to as [*nanori* readings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanori)). There are so many place names and person names having such special readings that even native Japanese speakers often cannot read them.

Comment: My 漢和辞典 has an entry for [江風]{かうふう} (old school pronunciation, obviously) with the sole listing for its meaning 川風.  So, indeed it seems like it shouldn't be a stretch at all to read 江風 as かわかぜ