# How are these names read?

Tags: readings, names, multiple-readings

In a recent *Asahi* article about changes to laws governing Japanese names, this sentence appeared:

戦争【せんそう】に突入【とつにゅう】すると、「勝【?】」「進【?】」

*When the war broke out, "?" and "?" were used.*

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASQD955GDQD3UTIL01T.html?iref=comtop_ThemeLeftS_03

Other names listed in the article are

「千代」

「久」

「寿」

「愛」

「結」

「麻」

「葵」

「萌」

Unfortunately, none of these names appear with their readings, and the entry for just the first name on jisho.org is quite long:

https://jisho.org/search/%22%E5%8D%83%E4%BB%A3%22%20%23names

How are these names commonly pronounced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just educated guesses because you should [never assume you can read someone's name](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5529/78)!

These two are most likely [「勝」]{まさる} and [「進」]{すすむ}.  But my confidence level varies with the rest of these:

[「千代」]{ちよ}

[「久」]{ひさし}

[「寿」]{ことぶき？}

[「愛」]{まな}

[「結」]{ゆい}

[「麻」]{あさ}

[「葵」]{あおい}

[「萌」]{きざし}

Comment: 萌 could be もえ I guess

Comment: I know a person whose name is 寿 (ひさし).

Answer (score 2):

This article started out as a description of common *names* (蒼, 凪, 陽葵), but at some point, it turned into a description of common *kanji* used in names. In particular, 麻 is almost never used as a name by itself, and I don't know how to read it naturally as a name (the author also says 自然にまつわる**漢字が**目立ち始めた).

Most of these kanji are typically used as part of longer names (e.g, 麻美【まみ】, 勝久【かつひさ】, 愛結【あゆ】). 千代 can be used on its own, but it's also used as a component (八千代【やちよ】, 竹千代【たけちよ】). Of course, each kanji has multiple readings, so you cannot assign a single furigana in this context.

But when used as a one-kanji name, these are typically read as follows:

千代: ちよ, 久: ひさし, 寿: ことぶき(female)/ひさし(male), 愛: あい/まな, 結: ゆい, 麻: ???, 葵: あおい, 萌: もえ.